# set_checkbox value not returned

Tags: php, codeigniter

[enter image description here][1]i want repopulate my form using edit button
once i clicked edit button it ll shows what are all the selected items are to be displayed

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck1" name="certid[]" 
  value="1" class="cbx"  <?php echo set_checkbox('certid','1');?>
```

Controller

```
   $data['getcert'] = $this->User_Model->getcert();

  output should be in the form of array 

   Array
  (
  [id] => 1
  [certificate_id] => 1
  [fee] => 500
  [APPNO] => 10001
  [regno] => 01107402042
  [certid] => 1
  [noc] => 2
  [paid] => 1000
  )


 <?php foreach($getcert as $student){ 
   echo '<pre>';
    print_r($student);
    echo '</pre>';
    ?>
 <td width="50px" align="center">1</td>
 <td>Transcripts  & Degree Certificate Attestation</td>
  <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" id="mycheck1" name="certid[]" 
   value="<?php echo (!isset($student['certid'])) ? 1 : $student['certid'] 
      ?>"
    class="cbx"  <?php echo set_checkbox('certid[]','1');?> ></td>
     <td> 500 </td>
    <td> <input type="number" id="primaryincome1"  min="1"  max="999" 
 name="noc[]" 
   value="<?php echo (!isset($student['noc'])) ? '' : $student['noc'] ?>"
   disabled> </td>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <td ><input type="text" id="totalamountremaining1"  name="txt" 
    class="text-right" value="<?php echo (!isset($student['paid'])) ? 0 : 
     $student['paid'] ?>"  size="5"></td>
      </div>

    that certid value only be placed in checkbox
```

This values are stored in db .how to assign that value in this view?

Comment: Going to need alot more information here. Are you already bringing the data from the database to populate the fields? If so, how, post an example of the rest of the work you've done for the form. What does your db structure look like? Post a picture. Certid is an array? How is it stored?\

Comment: check my post  i changed my coding

Comment: if all you have is one field, then why is certid input name denoted it as an array? `name="certid[]"`... where is the rest of your form/view?

Comment: using this array i fetch the values ([certid],
    [noc],
    [paid] . thats y

Comment: no, not that array, why is the input `name="certid[]"` and not `name="certid"` if you don't have more than 1 checkbox it doesn't make sense.

Comment: i am using totally 7 checkbox items . for insert method that certid[] is used. all boxes have same name only.

Comment: then show form **code** and table structure. *explain* how these 7 items contribute to table structure.

Comment: see if `echo set_checkbox('certid[]', $student['certid']);` works for you OR  `echo set_checkbox('certid[]', $student['certid'], 1);`

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="mycheck1" name="certid[]" 
       value="<?php echo (!isset($student['certid[]'])) ? '1' : $student['certid[]'] ?>"
        class="cbx">

Comment: not working .................

Comment: Can you add the code of `set_checkbox` to your question? Please do not add relevant information to the comment section, better edit the question

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answers to your question but you will get an idea how to do this.

In the HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="certid" value="<?php print base64_encode(serialize($result)); ?>">
```

And in the controller:

```
$data = unserialize(base64_decode($this->input->post('certid')));
```

Using this method you can pass the array data from the frontend to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Right so, apparently `set_checkbox()` is more of something to be used when repopulating fields from form validation. E.g. the field has a post value and that post value needs to be brought back when validation fails. So it's not really something for determining if the db field matches the checkbox value.

Now I'm assuming that the logic you want is that if the value in the db for `certid` is 1 then the checkbox should be checked. In which case you can do:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck1" name="certid[]" value="<?php echo (!isset($student['certid'])) ? 1 : $student['certid'] ?>" class="cbx" <?php if ($student['certid'] == 1):?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck1" name="certid[]" 
  value="1" class="cbx" <?php echo set_checkbox('certid','1', $certid==1;?>>`

with `$certid` as your db value

from manual:

> third (optional) parameter lets you set an item as the default (use boolean TRUE/FALSE)'

so you test your db value if it fits the checkbox value, thats it.